# Group by clause with multiple joins which both column have as of date

Tags: sql

i am trying to do a `group by` clause for `as_of_date` instead of `inner join`. i was wondering if this possible , i have tried below query but its prompting me error

When i tried using `main.as_of_date = ref.as_of_date` , it is working perfectly , however my objective is further optimise my query with `group by` clause

```
select 
'Wholesale Retail' as business_segment
, 'Deposit' as product
, main.as_of_date
, 'MY' as country
, ref.GFCID as gfcid
, 'DCIP_GFCID' as gfcid_typ
, cast(arrg_id as String) as arrg_id
, cast(arrg_desc as String) as arrg_desc
, 'NA' as interest_rate
, cast(ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD  as String) as ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD
, 'ME' as feed_period
, 'S_LR_DEP_MY_WR_INB_ME' as eap_table_name  

from gflmyasg_staging.S_LR_DEP_MY_WR_INB_ME main 
left join gflmyasg_staging.S_LR_CMN_MY_WS_GFCID ref 
    on main.DCIP_GFCID=ref.GFCID 
group by ref.as_of_date and main.as_of_date
```

I have using this query but it returned error

```
select 
'Wholesale Retail' as business_segment
, 'Deposit' as product
, main.as_of_date
, 'MY' as country
, ref.GFCID as gfcid
, 'DCIP_GFCID' as gfcid_typ
, cast(arrg_id as String) as arrg_id
, cast(arrg_desc as String) as arrg_desc
, 'NA' as interest_rate
, cast(ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD  as String) as ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD
, 'ME' as feed_period
, 'S_LR_DEP_MY_WR_INB_ME' as eap_table_name  
from gflmyasg_staging.S_LR_DEP_MY_WR_INB_ME main 
left join gflmyasg_staging.S_LR_CMN_MY_WS_GFCID ref 
    on main.DCIP_GFCID=ref.GFCID 
    and main.as_of_date=ref.as_of_date 
group by main.as_of_date;
```

Error : AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): ref.GFCID gfcid

I have tried researching on the usage of group by and found we can use group by main.as_of_date. what is the better approach on this or there is something that i missed out?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `ref.GFCID` and all the other fields listed in the `select` (`arrg_id`, `arrg_desc`, `ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD`): they need to be either in the `group by`, or be aggregated - for example `COUNT(ref.GFCID)`, or `COUNT(distinct ref.GFCID)`

```
select 
'Wholesale Retail' as business_segment
, 'Deposit' as product
, main.as_of_date
, 'MY' as country
,COUNT(ref.GFCID) as cnt_gfcid  
,COUNT(distinct ref.GFCID) as cnt_dist_gfcid  
-- , ref.GFCID as gfcid
, 'DCIP_GFCID' as gfcid_typ
--, cast(arrg_id as String) as arrg_id
--, cast(arrg_desc as String) as arrg_desc
, 'NA' as interest_rate
--, cast(ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD  as String) as ARRG_LIFE_CYC_STA_TYP_CD
, 'ME' as feed_period
, 'S_LR_DEP_MY_WR_INB_ME' as eap_table_name  
from gflmyasg_staging.S_LR_DEP_MY_WR_INB_ME main 
left join gflmyasg_staging.S_LR_CMN_MY_WS_GFCID ref 
    on main.DCIP_GFCID=ref.GFCID 
    and main.as_of_date=ref.as_of_date 
group by main.as_of_date;
```